# Ggplot2 stairtep graph won't join points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sequence of Surfaces that were touched in a room during patient care.

```
dput(sequence_contacts)
structure(list(value = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("FarPatient", "Patient", "Equipment", "HygieneArea", 
"Out"), class = "factor"), x = 1:25), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm trying to plot the sequence of contacts on along the x axis with the surface name on the y axis using a connected stair-step graph.
But I can't get the points to join up. Why not?

```
ggplot()+
geom_step(data= sequence_contacts, mapping=aes(x=x, y=value)) +
  geom_step(data= sequence_contacts, mapping=aes(x=x, y=value), direction="vh", linetype=3) +
  geom_point(data= sequence_contacts, mapping=aes(x=x, y=value, colour=x)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")+
  scale_x_continuous("Contact Number")+
  scale_y_discrete("Surface Category")
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `group=1` to `geom_step`?

Comment: How would you know to use this?